# Event on notification bar like Status bar android

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, android-notification-bar

I created a Notification using `Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT`. Now I want to use it as on/off switch just like bluetooth or wifi in Status bar.

I want to use it as on off switch for my service. If I click it, it will start the service and if I click it again it will off the service. Just like the bluetooth /wifi or other things in status bar. As I can't put anything on Status bar I want to use the notification bar in that way. Is it possible?

Comment: "want to use it as on/off switch", can you please explain what this means?

Comment: I want to use it as on off switch for my service. If I click it it will start the service and if I click it again it will off the service. Just like the bluetooth /wifi or other things in status bar.As I cant put anything on Status bar I want to use the notification bar in that way.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Pending intent that will launch your activty and put extras to know if u have to switch on/off.

```
// notification is clicked
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
intent.putExtra(Main.SWITCH_ON, true);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Extras bundle on the oncreate method

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null && extras.containsKey(SWITCH_ON) && extras.getBoolean(SWITCH_ON)) {
            launchMyMethod();
        }
```

Comment: have you used toggle switches to on-of?

Actually I want to use the notification itself as the switch. If clicked it will lunch a service. If again clicked it will stop the service. Is there is a way like it?